# Regular expression for simple math expressions

Tags: python, regex

As an exercise I was trying to come up with a regex to evaluate simple algebra like

```
q = '23 * 345 - 123+65'
```

From here I want to get '23', '*', '345', '-', '123', '+', '65'.

Now, I've searched similar questions, and other people have solved this. But what I really want to know is why *my* solution doesn't work.

Here's the best I got:

```
regexparse = '(\d+\s*(\*|\/|\+|\-)\s*)+(\d+\s*)'
```

Explanation

- (\d+\s*(*|/|+|-)\s*)+

  - ( One or more digits \d+ may be followed by whitespace \s* then must be followed by one of the symbols (*|/|+|-) then may be followed by more whitespace \s* and the whole thing must appear at least once )+
- (\d+\s*)

  - One or more digits which may be followed by whitespaces

However, when I run the code

```
m = re.match(regexparse, q)
print m.group(0)
print m.group(1)
print m.group(2)
print m.group(3)
```

I get

```
23 * 345 - 123+65
123+
+
65
```

So it's like the first block is matching the least amount possible of chars. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your regex:

```
(\d+\s*(\*|\/|\+|\-)\s*)+(\d+\s*)
```

`(\d+\s*(\*|\/|\+|\-)\s*)` will match the first part of your expression: `23 *`  and store `*` in the second group.

Then the `+` makes it repeat, but because repeating capture groups retain only their last match, it will discard `23 *`  and `*` and instead match `345 -`  and `-` in the second group.

The `+` works again on the next repeat to discard the last capture and instead capture `123+` in the first group and `+` in the second.

Next, `+` cannot repeat any more, so it stops, and `(\d+\s*)` starts matching to get `65`.

---

The fact that repeating capture groups store only the last capture is how regex works by design and is like this in all regex engines AFAIK.

---

Further elaboration:

There's a difference between matching repeatedly and capturing repeatedly. Try: `(\d)+` on `12345` and you will see that only `5` will be captured. It's like that because you the paren is assigned a particular group capture. The first group is assigned group 1 and if you have many captures for group 1, you can only keep 1 and that's the last. This is how regex works, unfortunately, [as per the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects):

> If a group matches multiple times, only the last match is accessible

---

If you want to get your desired output, you might use `re.findall` and match with `\d+|[+/*-]`:

```
import re
q = '23 * 345 - 123+65'
regexparse = r'\d+|[+/*-]'
elem = re.findall(regexparse, q)
print(elem)
#=> ['23', '*', '345', '-', '123', '+', '65']
```

Comment: Same thing that aliteralmind said, but if + only keeps the last match, why is it that \d+ keeps the whole thing? Also, but I can repeat and keep the whole thing?

Comment: Ok, for being the first to both explain what was going on and offering a close fix, I'm going to mark it correct. But may copy-past your comments into the answer body, please? For organization.

Comment: @oneloop Okay, I can do that. I'll remove my comments after that then.

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak of regex in general, as I don't know python, but your problem is that in

```
(\d+\s*[\*/+-]\s*)+(\d+\s*)
```

This portion

```
(\d+\s*[\*/+-]\s*)+
```

Is being repeated and when it's completely done evaluating, you only see the final one.

Comment: I know that, but why? Why is it that when I have (  )+ it's "being repeated but you only see the final one", whereas when I have \d+ it's being repeated, but I see the full thing?

Comment: Your regex is matching a portion of what you want, repeatedly. There is no "whole thing". If you want every match, you have break down your regex and loop through its matches, in order to intercept them. By executing your regex at once, *which has a repeating group* and then something else *after* it, you're only going to see the final one. It is indeed matching every one, but every one *but the last* is being immediately discarded.

Answer (score 2):

Simply try this.

```
import re
q = '23 * 345 - 123+65'
regexparse = r'(\d+)|[-+*/]'
for i in re.finditer(regexparse, q):
    print i.group(0)
```

output:

```
23
*
345
-
123
+
65
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is confusing. Better to use `re.split()` for this purpose:

```
q = '23 * 345 - 123+65'
print re.split('\s*([-+/*])\s*', q)
```

Outputs:

```
['23', '*', '345', '-', '123', '+', '65']
```